# SSH Connection through a Reverse (Remote) SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel

This is the setup I have :

- a Linux box A inside a LAN behind a firewall.
- a Linux server with a fixed IP address that is accessible from the internet.

I want to be able to connect to the Linux box that is behind a firewall from afar via ssh.
I have read about ssh tunneling and it occurred to me that this could be my solution.
I was able to open a remote ssh tunnel between the A and B. But I can't figure out how to use this tunnel to control A via ssh or if it's even possible.
e.g : connect from my laptop to A via B.

This is the command as I understood it to open the tunnel :

```
ssh -R 2022:localhost:22 user@serverB
```

(requests via port 2022 transferred to port 22(ssh) on the target machine) via user@serverB.

After I open this tunnel what should be the actions to connect via ssh to the target machine?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring is "SSH REMOTE FORWARDING", and is properly explained in the "**man ssh**", regarding the "**-R**" option.

```
> man ssh
[...]
 -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
    Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to 
    be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.
    This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the remote 
    side, and whenever a connection is made to this port, the
    connection is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is 
    made to host port hostport from the local machine.
    [...]
```

In your context, where:

- a Linux box A (LINUX_BOX_A) inside a LAN behind a firewall.
- a Linux server B (SERVER_B) with a fixed IP that is accessible from the internet

SSH remote forwarding can be used to reach LINUX_BOX_A from SERVER_B. The only condition is: LINUX_BOX_A ***MUST*** be able to connect via SSH to SERVER_B.

To achieve this goal you need:

1. on LINUX_BOX_A:

`LINUX_BOX_A:~ $ ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 user@SERVER_B`

this will open an ssh connection from LINUX_BOX_A to SERVER_B that will be used for the remote, incoming, connection.

After above ssh connection is established, you can:

2. on SERVER_B:

`SERVER_B:~ $ ssh -p 2222 user@localhost`

such ssh-connection, launched on SERVER_B, will be directed to the 2222 port listening on localhost that... is binded to the previous ssh connection. So this will be an "ssh connection within another ssh connection".

Some additional notes:

- consider that if the first ssh-connection will timeout and/or fall down for whatever reason (including: killed by local firewall, due to inactivity), you'll be unable to remote-forward/remotely_connect;
- as it's important to leave the first ssh connection active for really long time, you might find useful to launch such ssh within a "[screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)" session

A final note: Obviously, all of the above has some (potentially serious) security implications that are out of scope of this answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is just what i was looking for!. Regarding security issues my first option was port forwarding on the router. But as i understood this had even worse security implications and also problems with the company that the LAN belongs to regarding changing their router configurations.

Answer (score 3):

### I have drawn some sketches

The machine, where the ssh tunnel command is typed is called **»your host«**.

[image: ssh tunnel starting from local]

---

[image: ssh tunnel starting from remote]

### Introduction

1. local: `-L Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.`

   `ssh -L sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **local** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from the `connectToHost` machine.
2. remote: `-R Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.`

   `ssh -R sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **remote** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from your local machine.

### Additional options

- `-f` tells ssh to background itself after it authenticates, so you don't have to sit around running something on the remote server for the tunnel to remain alive.
- `-N` says that you want an SSH connection, but you don't actually want to run any remote commands. If all you're creating is a tunnel, then including this option saves resources.
- `-T` disables pseudo-tty allocation, which is appropriate because you're not trying to create an interactive shell.

### Your example

The third image represents your case. The computer behind the firewall, you called it **A**, is your host, because you have to execute the ssh command on this computer, to open the tunnel to the localhost of your host (see third image).

The remotehost (in the image) is your **serverB** (which is accessible from everywhere).

```
ssh -R 2022:localhost:22 user@serverB
```

All connection attempts to the green port `2022` are forwarded through the ssh tunnel to the pink port `22` on the your host’s localhost (the firewalled computer).

Now you can *ssh* from anywhere in the internet to the remotehost (you called **serverB**) on port 2022 (with the command: `ssh -p 2022 user@serverB` from any machine in the world) and will be connected to your firewalled computer. That means, you can control this computer.

### Automatic reconnection

You can write a script `startTunnelToHidden` that keeps the tunnel alive and re-establishes the connection, every time it gets lost. It is a good idea to start this script inside a screen session and even better to start it with ssh-agent to be able to connect with a public key (because, otherwise how would you enter the password? It is possible, but better to use a public key).

To open the tunnel on the firewalled computer, enter:

screen ssh-agent bash
ssh-add
startTunnelToHidden 2022:localhost:22 user@serverB

Or put this in `/etc/rc.local` (so that the tunnel gets opened on boot of the firewalled computer):

(sleep 2m; su - userOnA -c 'screen -S tunnelToHidden -d -m startTunnelToHidden 2022:localhost:22 serverB') &

The content of the bash script `startTunnelToHidden`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Opens and restarts a remote ssh tunnel (in case it gets disconnected).

MinReconnectTime=$((1*60))
MaxReconnectTime=$((30*60))
RTime="$MinReconnectTime"
TimeUnit="s"

count=0
while true; do
  ((count++))
  echo "Open tunnel (try number $count)"
  date

  ConnTime=$(date +%s)
  # Example: Open tunnel to remotehost, which forwards connections from the
  # remote’s localhost:10002 to the local port 22. »-N« means do not execute
  # any command (no command prompt), »-T« means no tty, and
  # »-o ServerAliveInterval=60« to keep the connection alive:
  #   ssh -N -T -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -R 10002:localhost:22 remotehost

  ssh -N -T -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -R $@
  DisconnTime=$(date +%s)

  SSHTime=$(($DisconnTime-$ConnTime))
  echo "SSHTime=${SSHTime}${TimeUnit}"
  echo "Excited Tunnel!"

  # it takes 63s for ssh to timeout, minreconntime is 60s, therefore
  # 2*minrectime
  if [ $SSHTime -gt $(($MinReconnectTime*2)) ]; then
    RTime=$MinReconnectTime
  else
    ((RTime*=2))
    if [ $RTime -gt $MaxReconnectTime ]; then
      RTime=$MaxReconnectTime
    fi
  fi                                                                                                                                                                      
  echo "Waiting $RTime$TimeUnit"
  sleep $RTime
done
```

Reattach the screen session with your tunnel with
screen -r tunnelToHidden

Answer (score 1):

If you control the firewall you can use port-fowarding on it to avoid the use of a reverse-ssh (it will be more stable).

Comment: But open to everyone.

Comment: Yes this was my first idea but the company that owns the LAN does not want us playing with their router configuration.